# How to make line graph, or bar graph with different categories on excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I don't know anything about Excel and I've been trying this for over an hour. I had to do an experiment for class that asks if hair color relates to height.

I have the hair color and height of 20 different people. I do not know how to put it in Excel and when I do, the graph is blank, the axes are wrong. Please Help. This is the information I have.

```
Brown       5'4,    5'10,   5'1,    5'4, 6'5
Drk Brown   6'6,    5'5,    5'5     
Black       5'4,    5'9,    5'0     
Blonde      5'8,    5'9,    5'8,    5'6 
Red         5'7,    5'7         
Light Brown 5'2,    5'2         
Med. Brown  5'4
```

Comment: What sort of graph are you trying to create, do you want to just display the counts? If so you need a `COUNT` column to count the total number of heights per colour. Generally homework questions are off-topic here as it is meant to be a learning exercise for you.

Comment: I don't think Excel understands that format of number; your heights are almost certainly being treated as text. You'll need to get them into actual numbers - I recommend converting them to raw inches.

Answer (score 1):

1. format your data to have only one value per cell (as in picture below)
2. calculate average of row in the first empty column (formula in the example: `=AVERAGE(B2:F2)`)
3. insert a line chart based on the data

   - for each series except the "average": right click on the series - line color - no line
   - delete the legend

This way you've created a chart showing average height by hair colour, and also height distribution of people.

[image]

Comment: Just need to point out that the heights given are in feet and inches. 5'10 is 5 foot, 10 inches (12 inches = 1 foot). 5.1 feet != 5'10.

Comment: @Burgi: I know, but I've never worked with feet in Excel, and I think it's not really relevant to chart creation.

Comment: True but it does make your averages incorrect. My comment was more to help clarify for the OP if they took your data "as is" and wondered why they got different answers.